# .htaccess and ?_escaped_fragment_=

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file now looks like (and nothing else):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ test.php$1 [QSA,L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

When i am trying to request this url:
http://example.com/test?_escaped_fragment_=blog=123&ggg=3

I am see html from test controller, not my test.php file. Please help, what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your first rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule !^test\.php$ test.php [L]
```